# unable to navigate to settings screen using navigationoptions when it is run without render function

Tags: react-native

While writing the code, not in render function the button is not navigating to the page/screen.
it is showing cannot find variable 'this.navigation.navigate'
**OnPress**function is just giving out error

```
static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: 'Review Jobs',
    headerRight: (
        <Button
            onPress={() => this.navigation.navigate('settings')}
            title="Settings"
            color="#fff"
        />
    ),
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it like this:

```
render() {
return (
  <View>
   <Button title="show me settings" onPress={this.GoToSettings} />
  </View>
 );
}


GoToSettings= () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings');
 };
```

### edit 1

oh sorry i think i misunderstood it in the first place

you need to pass the values (({navigation})) through the Fat Arrow funktion otherwise the onPress function cant work with it

this i hopefully what you are searching for:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation}) => ({
  title: "Review Jobs",
  headerRight: <Button title="Settings" onPress={()=>{ 
                 navigation.navigate('settings'); }} />,
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You shold use a **fat arrow function** and pass the `{navigation}` az props to the `static navigationOptions`.

Your desired code would be:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    headerTitle: "Review Jobs",
    headerRight: (
        <Button
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("settings")}
            title="Settings"
            color="#FFF"
        />
    ),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need pass the navigation in parameter, like this.

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    headerTitle: 'Review Jobs',
    headerRight: (
        <Button
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('settings')}
            title="Settings"
            color="#fff"
        />
    ),
}
```